# UIActionSheet crashes after appearing again on iPad

Tags: ipad, crash, uiactionsheet

the UIActionSheet crashes after it appears the second time through..

.H file

```
..UIActionSheetDelegate>{

 UIActionSheet *popupQuery;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *popupQuery;
```

.M file

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {

if (popupQuery.visible) {
    NSLog(@"popupQuery isVisible");

    [popupQuery dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];

    return;
}else{


popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Readibility" otherButtonTitles:@"Email URL", @"Print", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
//[popupQuery showInView:self.view];


[popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:actionButton animated:YES];

[popupQuery release];
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you release `popupQuery` after showing it from `actionButton`, you relinquish ownership on the object. If the object gets deallocated then `popupQuery` will point to a deallocated object which when you do `popupQuery.visible` might give you a crash. Since you have it as a property, you can do this –

```
self.popupQuery = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Readibility" otherButtonTitles:@"Email URL", @"Print", nil] autorelease];
```

Remove the `release` statement at the end. Now the object will be valid when you `popupQuery.visible` or `self.poupQuery.visible` In this case, you will have the ownership and you can safely access the object.

Comment: Thank you so much. That autorelease tip really helped a lot. I was worried that I would keep allocating popup every time the action button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UIActionSheet`:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

> **Parameters**
>
> *buttonIndex*
>
> The index of the button that was clicked. Button indices start at 0.

Therefore the problem may be your `-1`.